# Stack Overflow on TcpClient (Recursion)

Tags: .net, recursion, stack-overflow, tcpclient

Because of the repeated calls to **new**, the following code may produce a stack overflow exception if left as-is:

```
async void Connect()
{
    try 
    {
        client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HandleException(e); // Most likely will be a SocketException e.g. connection refused
        Connect(); // Try to connect again
    }
}
```

While I could reduce the chances of this happening by e.g. adding a maximum number of retries before giving up and exiting the recursion, I'd rather write it so that memory is freed and stack overflow exceptions don't happen.

I thought about putting it in a while loop, but I think that will have the same problem, e.g.

```
while (!connected)
{
    try
    {
        client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        connected = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HandleException(e);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to avoid stack overflow exceptions here aside from having an arbitrarily defined maximum number of retries?

Comment: No, the loop will not have the same problem, but why would you want this kind of infinite loop anyway? What if you have specified the wrong ip address or port? It will never complete, doesn't having that timeout sound like a better deal alltogether? I would use a loop with both a timeout on the connect as well as a maximum number of attempts before giving up.

Comment: The infinite-ness is just to show my point; in reality I have a maximum number of retries, but I know that it's theoretically possible to get stack overflow exceptions using this approach, and I wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: There is **always** a theoretical possibility of getting a stack overflow exception, but the recursive approach is *much* more prone to it. The loop is the best option here.

Comment: You're right, the loop works without producing an exception (so far). I think I misunderstood how things are scoped inside loops; I guess loop variables only exist for one iteration and then go out of scope, so they don't keep chewing up memory. I will use a loop and also keep my maximum number of retries, and possibly add an overall timeout too. Thanks! If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll do it myself in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lasse said in his comments:

a. The loop does not have the same behaviour as recursion when it comes to memory and scope, so using that is safer here.

b. It's always technically possible to run into stack overflow exceptions, but some approaches like recursion are typically more prone to it than regular loops.

I have ultimately implemented a loop with some extra conditions for e.g. max number of retries.

Answer (score 0):

I think if we close socket gracefully (by adding SocketException) then we can avoid Stackoverflow no matter how many times recursive method calls Connect(). Further, in my opinion, it doesn't make sense calling Connect() method instantly if it gets fail to connect due to any given reason. I think giving a small break before calling it again will avoid to face similar error continuously without break.

You may try this:

```
async void Connect()
    {            
        Socket socket = null; //namespace System.Net.Sockets
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
            socket = client.Client; 
        }
        catch(SocketException se) //All socket related exceptions will be caught here
        {
            if (socket != null)
                socket.Close();
            //better to write exception in the log to fix the problem
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10); //Wait for few seconds before retrying
            Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HandleException(e); 
            //Connect(); // Try to connect again
        }
    }
```